# Several SPARQL queries via Jena command line

Tags: sparql, jena

Is it possible to put several SPARQL queries into one file (like SQL SELECTs) and use it for tdbquery.bat Jena command line tool?

```
tdbquery.bat --loc=../data_dir --query=several_queries.sparql
```

I can do it in Java code but may be I can do it via tdbquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't run multiple queries with a single file.

But you can write your own `.bat` file that simply runs `tdbquery` multiple times, with a separate `.sparql` file for each call. That's probably simpler than cracking out the Java.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I can but I run my queries with inference(OWLMicroReasoner) during run time and it takes 14 hours for each query.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to run Fuseki in the background and use the the SOH command line tools to make the queries.  (Or a program to send the queries to the server like curl or wget.)